# Difference between running an executable from a folder and from command prompt?

Tags: parameters, executable, exe, command-prompt

I'm having a weird issue where I'm unable to run an executable properly.

If I double click or hit return using the icon, it's as if the application tries to run the executable with the parameter /help. (More exactly socrm.exe /help) (there's no parameters set for the file)

If I try to run socrm.exe through command prompt without any parameters this works fine.

My question would be: What's the difference between running an executable from a folder and running it from command prompt without any parameters?

This error seems to occur only on WinXP 32bit machines, when trying the exact same application on Win7 32/64 this works fine.

Could it be that some .dll files aren't properly registered?

Thanks in advance.

Appreciate any answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is something in your registry that opens this file with a parameter each time or the `"socrm.exe"` executes itself again with the /help parameter. How do you know it opens with the /help parameter? Anyway, there is actually no big difference between `"the user click"`
and open an executable with the commandline. Behind the scenes, your program get's executed as a child process of CMD and I think your program also gets it's user-rights from it's parent process. Hope I could help a little.

Comment: Good point, I'm actually not sure if the executable runs with /help or another similar parameter. I just know that it displays the same information as if you run it with /help or /?. I was unable to re-create the same information with any other parameter or just jibberish. (i.e. /ojwefojfw)

Thanks for explaining how the executable works though.